# How to dynamically inject services into a grails custom artefact

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, grails-plugin

So I created a plugin that introduces a custom artefact "Guard" (guard classes resides in: /grails-app/guards).  Right now my plugin works by making the grailsApplication aware of the new artefact.  So if I call grailsApplication.getGuardClasses() the behavior performs as expected.

My problem is that I want to be able to dynamically inject services into my guard classes, like so:

```
Class ExampleGuard {

     def exampleService

}
```

I have found solutions on this website that give a static solution, that either goes of Holders, or the application context to get the bean by name.  This is not what I want because I essentially want this to be autowired up to that when people use my plugin they can use dynamic injection of services in the guard classes.

UPDATE:
This is how I was accessing my Guard class.

```
def guard = grailsApplication.getArtefact("Guard","marketplace.TestGuard").newInstance()
```

Calling .newInstance() nullifies all fields on the class including the injected spring beans which is why injected classes will be null:

```
assert guard.sampleService == null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your plugin discovers all of the `Guard` classes and adds them to the spring application context, those beans will automatically be subject to dependency injection.  This is how all of the built in artifacts work and how artifacts provided by plugins work, Quartz Jobs for example.

EDIT:

As an exmaple...

```
class GuardsPlugin {

    // ...

    def doWithSpring = {
        application.guardClasses.each { guardClass ->
            "${guardClass.propertyName}"(guardClass.clazz) { bean ->
                bean.autowire = "byName"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then if you have a class like `MySpecialGuard` and you reference if from a controller (for example) with something like this...

```
class MyController {
    def mySpecialGuard

    def someAction() {
        // mySpecialGuard should be DI'd into this
        // controller and mySpecialGuard should itself
        // have been subjected to DI
    }
}
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Currently if I type "def exampleService" or "ExampleService exampleService" and try to call methods off that variable it says that the service is null

Comment: That is because your guard has not been subjected to DI.

Comment: Would you be able to tell me what DI stands for?

Comment: DI is Dependency Injection.

Comment: I really appreciate all your help, your example shows how to make the Guard class injectable.  I want to inject artefacts onto the guard like in my code snipplet.  My confusion may lie here: Is there a difference between making a class injectable, vs being able to inject artefacts within the class?  I ask because your example may cover both cases and I am not aware of it, again thanks!

Comment: All of the beans in the application context are subjected to DI.  If you register guard beans in the context as I have shown above, those guard beans will be subjected to DI.  In addition that, the guard beans can be DI'd into other beans like controllers, services, etc.  That means if a Service defines a reference to a Guard, the Guard will be auto injected into the service.  If a Guard defines a reference to a Service, the Service will be auto injected into the Guard.

Comment: Great answer I guess it's a two way street when it comes to DI, thanks for the detailed responses I appreciate it, happy coding :)

Comment: Is there a place we can chat?  I am baffled as to why I am still getting null pointer exceptions (I have been working at this for 3 hours now), I have doWithSpring and an onChange closure defined.  I also have debug messages so I see that my guard class is being made into a bean with the code snipplet you added above.  Yet when I try to inject a service onto that guard in the app and use it I get null pointer exceptions (injecting that guard into other classes also doesn't work).

Comment: This is a super simple thing to do. I am happy to chat with you to work it out, but I am on my way out the door for lunch. I will check in later and we can setup a Skype or something. In the meantime, if you want to push a sample plugin to github which contains your plugin code, fixing it will be like a 60 second mission.  Will talk soon.

Comment: Checkout the project at https://github.com/jeffbrown/artifactdemo.  Run the app under the `demoapp` directory and send a request to `demo/index` and that will demonstrate that guards are injected into services and services are injected into guards.  That app is very crude and simple, intended only to serve as a demonstration of issues related to the question here.

Comment: After the discussion at github I decided that this answer has caused more confusion than I anticipated.  I attempted to delete it but StackOverflow won't allow me to delete an answer that has been accepted.  I apologies for the trouble.  I am sorry that I can't help.  Best of luck getting it sorted out.

Comment: I am going to leave this open and when I find my solution I will post.

Comment: Great.  I am going to leave the demo app that I posted on github alone, so it is still out there for reference.  I read your comments on github that said you couldn't make it work and for some reason the wrapper isn't there for you.  It all works for me and without more info on your setup it is hard to say why it doesn't work for you.  Anyway, I will leave that out there in case you find it helpful.  Best of luck.